# Where does Django build its URLs?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I am playing around with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and am trying to work through a tutorial for [Creating and Running Your First Django Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/step-4-creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html). My solution is and will remain self hosted at [Atlantis-Zero](https://atlantis-zero.net/) using Aprelium's [Abyss Web Server X1](https://aprelium.com/abyssws/download.php). The server has seen set to reverse proxy *127.0.0.1:8000* where the Django development server is running, and the virtual location on the server is [DjangoHelloWorld](https://atlantis-zero.net/DjangoHelloWorld/).

When trying to access the [admin](https://atlantis-zero.net/DjangoHelloWorld/admin/) application and viewing the page source, code like the following comes up:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us" >
<head>
<title>Log in | Django site admin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/login.css" />




<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
</head>
...
```

Where are URLs globally generated within Django? Either I need to modify how they are being created so that `/DjangoHelloWorld/` is part of the path to expected resources, or I need to change some setting so that the development server realizes that it is not at the root of the web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the following forum exchange to be helpful:

[DJANGO framework under FastCGI on ABYSS](https://aprelium.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9017)

It says that Abyss supports URL rewriting, and that may help with getting your links correct.

---

Now to actually get Django and Abyss configured as suggested, this thread might be more useful:

[Django (Python) with FastCGI](https://aprelium.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14566)

It provides a link to a tutorial on the Django website's wiki.

---

If you want to view the tutorial directly, you will want to go here:

[Django on Windows with Abyss (FastCGI)](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithAbyss)

A copy of this tutorial can be found down below.

---

## Django on Windows with Abyss (FastCGI)

### Background

Developing with Django in Windows and want a more production-like environment? This is a solution I've got working now that seems really nice and lightweight.

### Prerequisites:

This assumes you've got your Python and Django environment up and working and prepared it for FastCGI as detailed here: http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/fastcgi/ Download and install version 2.5 or higher of the Abyss web server from http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/ (free for personal use).

The text below is borrowed and modified from the Rails configuration details at: http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/ror.html.

Here it assumes you've got a my-site project under C:\django and want to serve your other content from C:\django\public_html.

*This was tested using Python 2.5 and Django development version (SVN trunk).*

### Configuration:

#### Start Django in FastCGI mode

```
C:\> cd django\mysite
C:\django\mysite> python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=3033
```

- Create an empty file called dispatch.fcgi in public_html. This seems to be required for the URLRewrite of Abyss to kick in. (There might be some other prettier solution to this though.)

#### Run Abyss Web Server and open its console

- Select the host that will serve the Django application:

  - If you have Abyss Web Server X2, you can create a new one for that purpose.
  - If you have Abyss Web Server X1, you'll have to use the unique available host.
- Press the Configure button associated with the host you have selected (in the Hosts table).
- Select General.

  - Enter in the Documents Path field: `C:\django\public_html`

    #### this is not a path - what is the correct text here?
  - Press OK.
- Select Scripting Parameters and press Add in the Scripting Parameters table.

  - Set Interface to FastCGI (Remote - TCP/IP sockets).
  - Enter 127.0.0.1 in Remote Server IP Address and set Port field to 3033.
  - Make sure the Type is Standard.
  - Press Add in the Extensions table, enter fcgi in the Extension field, press OK, then press OK a second time.
- Select URL Rewriting, press Add in the URL Rewriting Rules table.

  - Enter in the Virtual Path Regular Expression field: `^(.*)$`
  - Press Add in the Conditions table.
  - Set Variable to REQUEST_FILENAME, set Operator to Is not a file, and press OK.
  - Press Add one more time in the Conditions table.
  - Set Variable to REQUEST_FILENAME, set Operator to Is not a directory, and press OK.
  - Set If this rule matches to Perform an internal redirection.
  - Set Redirect to to: /dispatch.fcgi?$1
  - Press OK.

Apply the modifications

- Press Restart to restart the server.

Test the application and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

go to your project folder where you have wsgi.py and settings.py; there is a urls.py file there, inside the file you'll find the admin urlpattern and you can customize the name to whatever you like.Also to access the admin page you must run `python manage.py createsuperuser` in order to get a staff account